# AngularJS and Express - Routing multiple urls

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm currently trying to write a service with the MEAN stack to handle actions on a game. I've followed boiler plates up to the point where I now need to add custom actions. 
I have a game model which I can do the usual, save, update, delete on. But I want to add actions like join/leave game. I have tried this currently, for the game service:

```
window.angular.module('ngff.services.games', [])
.factory('Games', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource(
            'games/:gameId/:actionId',
        {
            gameId: '@_id',
            actionId: '@actionId'
        },
        {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {
                    actionId: null
                }
            },
            join: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    actionId: 'join'
                }
            },
            leave: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    actionId: 'leave'
                }
            }
        }
    );
}]);
```

Update works correctly, but my other requests always seems to default post to games/:gamesId without adding the actionId on the end. How can I change the location that my form posts to? 
I already have the backend worked out, and manually posting to my apis works fine. 
I had all this working without angular, but I've never used it before and I'm a little stuck.

Thanks

Ryan